# Unable to compile code on arround all latest released studio includind 3.0.0 and 2.3.3 and 2.1.1 having following error

Tags: android, build.gradle

Error:Could not find com.android.support:design:26.0.0.
Required by:
    project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android Support Library dependencies are now available from Google's Maven repository at maven.google.com—instead of downloading from the Android SDK Manager.

Try following this instructions:

http://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: Thanks @Angel Castelo